# redirect to custom not found jsp page

Tags: java, servlets, picocontainer

I've got HttpServlet. It redirects user to different jsp pages, depends on action user want to do.
For example `http://localhost:8080/collections/index.do` redirects to index.jsp.
Different action I keep in picocontainer like this

```
<component-instance key="index">
    <com.epam.collections.web.IndexAction/>
</component-instance>
```

When user write previous url in browser - 
1) I get action name - `index`

```
String name = getActionName(req);
```

2) Get action from picocontainer

```
Action action = (Action) pico.getComponentInstance(name);
```

3) Perform action  - return string which represents jsp page name

```
String view = action.exec(req, resp);
```

where exec method is

```
public String exec(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    return "index";
}
```

4) Forward user to `index.jsp page`

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
            "/WEB-INFO/pages/" + view + ".jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

I want to forward user to page `notfound.jsp` when there is not action in picocontainer. For example some `blabla.do` should return `notfound.jsp` page. But when I do like this

```
if (action == null) {
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
                "/WEB-INF/jsp/notfound.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        return;
    }
```

because `getComponentInstance` returns `null` when action does not exist in xml file - I've got error 500

Also I want to redirect to this page when I write sth without `.do` at all. For example `ddd.dd`, `plain` and etc. But I've got 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) to handle 404 errors you need to setup 404 handler in web.xml
2) you got 500 err, cause probably something is wrong about your jsp page, you need to check jsp code carefully
3) the way you use pico is an antipattern, check pico docs